# How to do regression modelling in R multiple (one at a time) to multiple column of a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, regression

I'm trying to do regression modeling in R. I have a dataframe of 100000 rows and 51 columns. The first few columns are response variables and the rest of the columns are predictor variables. Where my goal is to execute `"ranger"` for random forest model on each response variable at a time for all predictor variables and generate distinct output objects for every response variables. I've some other dataframes where the number of response variable is more than 100, so it is not feasible to add column names of every response variable and predictor variable every time doing the regression analysis.

This is a short version of the dataframe, in which the response variable name starts with `"EE..."` and the predictor variables end with `"_h16"`. The dataframe looks like this below,

```
head(GC05cr_h16_dat3)
# A tibble: 7 × 25
EE87865ln1   EE87866ln1   EE87895ln1  blood_vessel_h16 adrenal_gland_h16 bone_element_h16 bronchus_h16 
       <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>             <dbl>            <dbl>        <dbl>         
1    0.00391     0.00326    0.00332       0                 0                1            0             
2    0.00139     0.00116    0.00132       0                 0                0            0             
3    0.00360     0.00270    0.00469       1                 1                0            1             
4    0.00323     0.00348    0.00339       0                 0                1            0             
5    0.00323     0.00330    0.00382       0                 1                0            0             
6    0.00278     0.00208    0.00214       0                 0                1            0
```

What I am trying to do so far,

```
for (i in names(GC05cr_h16_dat3)[grep("EE", names(GC05cr_h16_dat3))]){
    rfR.res <- ranger(
      as.formula(paste(colnames(GC05cr_h16_dat3[ , i])), "~ ."),
                                data = GC05cr_h16_dat3, importance="impurity"
      ) 
    assign(paste0("rfR_Res_", names(GC05cr_h16_dat3)[i]), rfR.res, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  }
```

ERROR:

```
Error in formula.character(object, env = baseenv()) : 
  invalid formula "EE87865ln1": not a call
```

My expected output rf objects name would look like this....

```
rfR_Res_EE87865ln1
rfR_Res_EE87866ln1
rfR_Res_EE87895ln1
................
................
```

Comment: Can you put multiple variables on the left hand side of the formula? E.g.: `lm(cbind(mpg,disp) ~ cyl + wt, data=mtcars)` compared to `lm(mpg ~ cyl + wt, data=mtcars)` and `lm(disp ~ cyl + wt, data=mtcars)` separately.

Comment: No, it's not working. Only considering the second element `disp`.

Comment: Are you sure? Because `lm(cbind(mpg,disp) ~ cyl + wt, data=mtcars)` gives me two sets of coefficients in the result, one for `mpg` and one for `disp`

Comment: My bad, it's working. Is it possible to use column number instead of name as the number of x and y variable are quite high. 
Thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reformulate` is an useful function you can use to make formulas with strings.

Let’s consider the `mtcars` data set, you can run a regression this way:

```r
lm(reformulate(termlabels = c("disp", "wt"), response = "mpg"), data = mtcars)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = reformulate(termlabels = c("disp", "wt"), response = "mpg"), 
#>     data = mtcars)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)         disp           wt  
#>    34.96055     -0.01772     -3.35083
```

In this example, `termlabels` and `response` are vectors you can generate the
way you decide. For example, since you identify the variables by position, you can
subset and loop to run all regressions without creating another data frame.

I would do something as follow:

```r
head(mtcars)
#>                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#> Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

1. pick your variables

```r
all_variables <- names(mtcars)
response_variables <- all_variables[c(1, 3)]
predictors <- all_variables[-c(1, 3)]
```

2. Run the models

```r
all_models <- lapply(
  response_variables,
  function(x) lm(reformulate(termlabels = predictors, response = x), data = mtcars)
) |>
  setNames(response_variables)
```

You end with a list with one model per response variable

```r
all_models
#> $mpg
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = reformulate(termlabels = predictors, response = x), 
#>     data = mtcars)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)          cyl           hp         drat           wt         qsec  
#>    12.55052      0.09627     -0.01295      0.92864     -2.62694      0.66523  
#>          vs           am         gear         carb  
#>     0.16035      2.47882      0.74300     -0.61686  
#> 
#> 
#> $disp
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = reformulate(termlabels = predictors, response = x), 
#>     data = mtcars)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)          cyl           hp         drat           wt         qsec  
#>     18.5336      15.5757       0.6398      10.6131      81.6154     -11.6838  
#>          vs           am         gear         carb  
#>    -11.8042      -3.1052       6.5678     -31.3033
```

PS: A good resource with example for something similar is [chapter 25 of the book R for data science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html)

<sup>Created on 2023-08-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>